# Qt - What is meant by those lines of code

Tags: c++, qt, dialog

In the `C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4` book, part of creating a dialog application, there was the following `main.cpp` file:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>
#include "ui_gotocelldialog.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);
Ui::GoToCellDialog ui;
QDialog *dialog = new QDialog;
ui.setupUi(dialog);
dialog->show();
return app.exec();
}
```

Can you just describe those lines of code?

```
    Ui::GoToCellDialog ui;
    QDialog *dialog = new QDialog;
    ui.setupUi(dialog);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"ui_gotocelldialog.h" is a file generated automatically based on the file "gotocelldialog.ui" which contains the GUI for the dialog. Ui::GoToCellDialog::setupUi() must be called for the UI to be initialized.

Comment: Why is `dialog` passed as a paramter?

Comment: Can you describe how the three lines are working together more thoroughly?

Comment: It builds and lays out widgets as described by the gotocelldialog.ui file. The widgets it builds are placed inside the widget that is passed to it. In this case, the widget passed to it is a dialog.

Comment: @user588855: Think of setupUi() as "apply the UI the the dialog given". It adds widgets and sets up signal/slot connections defined in the UI file to the dialog.

Answer (score 3):

Lets take a look:

```
Ui::GoToCellDialog ui;
```

This line creates an instance of `GoToCellDialog`. As already have been said, this class automatically generated from the `gotocelldialog.ui` file. The use-case is:

1. Open qt-designer and make the interface you want.
2. Save the file (in our case `gotocelldialog.ui`)
3. In your .cpp file write `#include "ui_gotocelldialog.h"`
4. Now you can use the interface you designed
5. PROFIT????

Next:

```
QDialog *dialog = new QDialog;
```

This line creates new instance of the `QDialog` class that represents simple modal window (commonly called as *dialog*). But your window would be empty after this line. You need to place the controls, do you? How you can do this? Lets see:

```
ui.setupUi(dialog);
```

This line uses the interface you designed in the qt-designer. It places this interface to the newly created dialog. So you can see all the controls in the window. Pretty easy as for me.

Answer (score 2):

It [sets up](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#setupUi) the [ui described](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/designer-using-a-ui-file.html) by an qt ui xml file hosted inside of a [dialog window/qdialog](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdialog.html).